# How to handle solana pay transaction request error when server is separate from client?

Tags: transactions, solana-pay, phantom-wallet, error-handling

I am maintaining a server for transaction request . when I am scanning the qr on my client (browser) and wallet(Phantom) is making a request to the server which is running separately the code is working fine . But when there is some error occurring in post request in server (insuffient funds , Account not found in CreateTransfer method) I have not been able to display this error on wallet or in client code (as the post request is coming from wallet)

Comment: what is your client code? what library are u using?

Comment: in client taking a transaction amount in SOL showing the QR (transaction url with server address ) to make the transaction from wallet . I am using solana pay, solana/web3.js library's . And in server using the CreateTransfer (from solana/pay) function to create the transaction